# Is there any possibility to create new column based on list which check if value exist?

Tags: python, pandas, list, comparison

I need to create a boolean column based on two existing columns. I have two lists for two columns respectively. I need to check if the list1 item exists in column1 then it's true and list2 in column2 then true also. True + True = True

Here is an example:

```
list1 = ['Jack', 'Sam', 'Paul']
list2 = ['David', 'Detlef', 'Sam']

df:
Column1        Column2      
Selena         David
Jack           Sam
Sam            Detlef
```

Here is how I need a new column:

Expected Output:

```
    Column1        Column2     Check
    Selena         David       False
    Jack           Sam         True
    Sam            Detlef      True
```

Comment: `df['Col1'].isin(list1) & df['Col2'].isin(list2)`?

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't think it would be so easy.